# selection of meta-analysis model

Tags: meta-analysis

I have a dataset which includes different publications, and different studies within each publication,
different variables were also collected (i.e. var1, var2, and var3) and one effect size y.

var1: A, B, C
var2: 1, 2, 3, 4
var3: a, b

all are categorical varaibles

I am interested in studying the effect of these variables on y, specifically in comparing between a and b in var3.

However, Model Selection using the glmulti, reported that the best model is
"y ~ 1 + var1 + var2 + var1:var2"

Does this mean that I can't compare between levels of this variable (var3) because there is no significant effect on y?

sorry if I miss something because I am new with meta-analysis

Comment: If you were specifically interested in a variable the usual way would be to fit a model of your choice rather than rely on some procedure over which you have no control.

Comment: @mdewey Thank you for your response,, even I did use a meta-regression model, using each variable separately, to count for R2 explained by each variable, and this confirms the results of glmulti, as var1 and var2 explain about 50%, 30% heterogeneity, respectively,  while trying var3 (the one I am interested in), explained 0%